# Is there a flat namespace representation option for Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, representation, flat

In Eclipse there is a way to switch the representation mode of packages via a given ide menu. Please take a look at the screenshots i have made to illustrate this.
The screenshots show a hiearchy of packages, each containing one element.

- Hierarchial:

  [image]
- Flat:

  [image]

Is Visual Studio's Solution Explorer able to switch the hierarchial representation mode of namespaces into a flat one?

Note:
I am really only referring to the "representation" of the namespaces. I am not intended to change the namespaces' names or hierarchies in any way!

Motivation:
When dealing with larger projects where mixed contents is laid up in several namespace depths there comes a point when this things need to be reorganized. Lets say you have a couple of t4 templates with input and output files together in one namespace. Then things start to grow... you know the rest ;) Break up the big ball of mud (pattern) using SOC and usually the information inside one single file is not that helpful at that state. You see there are 20 files which should go into another NS and so on.

Maybe I am missing something really obvious here. I have already searched for plugins but it is really difficult to find something which matches this really specific topic in particular.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Comment: Do you mean in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, its Class View, or its Object Browser?

Comment: @J0e3gan I mean the solution explorer, because i usually work with that tool window. I have clarified this details in a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a built-in way to do this in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, which is where I presume you would like the option.

I also searched for a VS extension that adds this option to Solution Explorer and did not find one either.  Even VSCommands' Solution Explorer enhancements does not seem to offer this option.

*Now* what you might consider is using Visual Studio's Object Browser (View > Object Browser or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>) with its View Namespaces option enabled (its default being View Containers):

[image: Visual Studio 2012's Object Explorer with "View Namespaces" Enabled]

Scoped to My Solution, this seems to provide the flattened-namespaces view of a solution that you want.

**UPDATE:**

Following comments below, note that double-clicking types and members in Object Browser will open them to view & edit their code - similar to double-clicking files in Solution Explorer.

To help with switching between Solution Explorer and Object Browser, consider a couple possibilities.

**1)** Pin the Object Browser tab (and consider displaying pinned tabs in their own row via Visual Studio's Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > "Show pinned tabs in a separate row" (under the Pinned Tabs section of Tabs and Windows options)):

[image: Code Viewing & Editing with Object Browser as a Pinned Tab]

**2)** Dock Object Browser with Solution Explorer, below it etcetera - especially if you have a lot of screen real estate:

[image: Code Viewing & Editing with Object Browser Docked Like Solution Explorer]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :)
I have tested this and this works. well, but it is not exactly what i was looking for, as you already guessed. I think the next question would be if it is even possible for a plugin to manipulate the existing solution explorer into that direction. hehe

Comment: @isi: No problem. BTW, welcome to SO. If the answer works for you, please be sure to accept it.

Comment: This flat view brings a better overview for many situations, in those cases i am switching between the windows. Well it actually breaks the workflow way too much. Especially when moving things around on that level. If i wouldn't have access to a ReSharper license it would not be possible to modify the code from that window. To sum up, your idea and ReSharper in combination may be valid workaround.

Comment: @isi: You can double-click on types and members in Object Browser to view & edit their code just like you would in Solution Explorer.  Interesting, though: I use R# and use Object Browser; but I never noticed before that I can right-click on a type in Object Browser, then access the Refactor context menu.  Very cool.

Comment: yea that JetBrains stuff is awesome anyway :) cool that we both learned something new. But i am not really happy with that solution. Just because in other IDEs it is not neccessary to switch windows for this :/
But since work must be done ^^ you get the check for the accepted answer.
And thanks for quick replies!

Comment: Regarding "just like you would in Solution Explorer", this is not quite true - since types and members are the double-click targets in Object Browser versus files in Solution Explorer; but it is very similar - nearly equivalent if you do not have multiple types in code files.

Comment: My problem is that there are not only classes, i have design time templates, their outputs, inputs and classes. So at the end ReSharper only helps with the types. Actually i dont really need to inspect the files that much. It is really more a case of moving things around.
I will point that out in the question as well.